# Changing TextView? when i try it throws errors

Tags: android, android-layout

```
int resID = getResources().getIdentifier(getResources().getString(R.string.hello_world), "id", "com.example.test.projects");
       TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(resID);
       text.setText("cpu: " );
```

I cant seem to change the hello_world message ... it throws errors every time

Originally it was a lot more strait forward looking but :/ i noticed in my R file that my string for hello world didnt seem to have a ID like in many of the examples of changing the text view so i threw this together

heres where i made the layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

and my main xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.test.projects"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="7"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
    >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Don't you want a button to do the changing text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest a different approach, add an id to your TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/helloTextView"
    ... />
```

And you can change its text with:

```
TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.helloTextView);
text.setText("cpu: " );
```

(Also if your app crashes, you should always post your LogCat so we can see exactly what is happening.)

Comment: No trouble! You may know this but you can change the text _before_ the app starts by changing the `android:text=""` attribute as well.